# Orchar code-generation extension - error when supplying properties for `codegen part` command

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

i am trying to generate part with `codegen part` command.when i call this command without supplying `properties` it works well , like this :

```
> codegen part MyModule CustomPart
```

but when i supply even a single property it fails with following error :

```
> codegen part MyModule CustomePart /Properties: FOO:string 

Error executing command "codegen part MyModule CustomePart FOO:string"

Command arguments "MyModule CustomePart FOO:string" don't match command definition

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Command arguments "MyModule CustomePart  FOO:string" don't match command definition

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: Command arguments "MyModule CustomePart FOO:string" don
't match command definition]
   at Orchard.Commands.DefaultOrchardCommandHandler.Invoke(CommandContext contex
t) in d:\Currently Working\Varzesh\Site\src\Orchard\Commands\DefaultOrchardComma
ndHandler.cs:line 62
   at Orchard.Commands.DefaultOrchardCommandHandler.Execute(CommandContext conte
xt) in d:\Currently Working\Varzesh\Site\src\Orchard\Commands\DefaultOrchardComm
andHandler.cs:line 18
   at Orchard.Commands.DefaultCommandManager.Execute(CommandParameters parameter
s) in d:\Currently Working\Varzesh\Site\src\Orchard\Commands\DefaultCommandManag
er.cs:line 27
   at Orchard.Commands.CommandHostAgent.RunCommand(TextReader input, TextWriter
output, String tenant, String[] args, Dictionary`2 switches) in d:\Currently Wor
king\Varzesh\Site\src\Orchard\Commands\CommandHostAgent.cs:line 112
```

am i doing something wrong?

any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only problem is you have a space. So your command should look like this:

```
codegen part MyModule MyPart /Properties:Name:string,Age:int
```

Comment: huh...!i have tried any case except this one.thanks for your response pal,you saved my time.